# Get Commit messages of all branches, since their last merge with branch say 'A', that merged with branch 'A' after a last Tag

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am new to git and struggling with this. I have three branches - master, uat and dev. I want commit messages done on individual branches(uat and/or dev) if they are merged with master branch after the tag - **LatestVersion**(tag i created). I am trying to do it on git bash console.

Till now what i have tried is :

```
git checkout master
git branch --merged && git log LatestVersion..HEAD --oneline
```

This gives me commit message done on master branch. I want commit messages done on individual branches.

Any help will be very useful for me.

Comment: Looks to me like you're making this more complex than it needs to be... Does a simple `git log LatestVersion..dev` not do what you want?

Comment: Actually i don't know whether dev is merged with master or not and so does apply for uat. Hence, i cannot use dev in the command